# Inverse of a Function including Lambert W

Tags: lambert-w, inverse-function

Given the function:

\begin{equation}
Λ_{c,d,r}(x)=rx^{c-1}\left[ 1-\frac{1-(1-c)r}{rd}\ln x \right]^{d}
\end{equation}
I would like to prove that its inverse function exists and is defined as:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_{c,d,r}(x)=e^{-\frac{d}{1-c}\left[ W_k\left( B(1-x/r)^{1/d} \right) -W_k(B)\right]}
\end{equation}
where $d,r \in \mathbb{R}$, $c \in \mathbb{R}^{+}-\{0\}$, $B$ is a constant defined as:
\begin{equation}
B=\frac{(1-c)r}{1-(1-c)r}e^{\frac{(1-c)r}{1-(1-c)r}}
\end{equation}
Moreover, $W_k$ is the $k$-th branch of the *Lambert-W* function which is a solution of the equation:
\begin{equation}
x=W(x)e^{W(x)}
\end{equation}
*(we are only interested in the branches k=0 and k=-1 which represent real solutions.)*
My problem is that I am not able to actually do the work needed in order to acquire the *Lambert-W* form while attempting to solve the $\mathcal{E}=Λ^{-1}$.
I have tried both ways *(from $Λ$ to $\mathcal{E}$ and the inverse)* since I know the expression of the function which I am actually looking for but no luck yet.

Defining $α \equiv -(1-c)/d$ in order to get away with less typing, we now have:
\begin{align}
& \mathcal{E}_{c,d,r}(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{α}\left[ W_k\left( B(1-x/r)^{1/d} \right) -W_k(B)\right]} \Leftrightarrow 
\mathcal{E}^{a}_{c,d,r}(x)e^{W_k(B)}=e^{W_K\left(B(1-x/r)^{1/d}\right)}\Leftrightarrow \\ 
&\log \mathcal{E}^{a}_{c,d,r}(x)+W_k(B)={W_K\left(B(1-x/r)^{1/d}\right)} \Leftrightarrow \\
& W_k^{-1}\left( \log \mathcal{E}^{a}_{c,d,r}(x)+W_k(B) \right)=B(1-x/r)^{1/d} \Leftrightarrow \\
& \frac{W_k^{-1}\left( \log \mathcal{E}^{a}_{c,d,r}(x)+W_k(B) \right)}{B}=\left( 1-\frac{x}{r}\right)^{\frac{1}{d}} \Leftrightarrow \left[ \frac{W_k^{-1}\left( \log \mathcal{E}^{a}_{c,d,r}(x)+W_k(B) \right)}{B} \right]^d=1-\frac{x}{r}
\end{align}
Therefore:
\begin{equation}
x=r\left[1- \left[ \frac{W_k^{-1}\left( \log \mathcal{E}^{a}_{c,d,r}(x)+W_k(B) \right)}{B} \right]^d \right]
\end{equation}
Now, by making use of the *Lambert-W* property:
\begin{equation}
x=W(x)e^{W(x)} \Leftrightarrow W^{-1}(x)=W^{-1}\left[ W(x)e^{W(x)} \right]
\end{equation}
My guess is that I am close to the end now, by starting with $Ε$ and building my way up to $Λ$. But I am still not able to find out somehow what the $W^{-1}_k(x)$ would be. And I can see it is of vital importance in order to finish this one. 
Any ideas or suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Ok so after forcing myself to become familiar with the Lambert W, I continued where I left it from and ended up with the following:

\begin{equation}
Λ_{c,d,r}(x)=rx^{c-1}\left[ x^{1-c}-\left[ \frac{1-(1-c)r}{rd}\ln x \right]^d \right]
\end{equation}
But I am not able to see now how to get to the final form of it. I would like the whole bracket to be to the power of $d$ and also the term $x^{1-c}$ should not be there, according to the $Λ$ which I would like to have.

If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it. Thank you again.

Comment: If $W^{-1}_k(u)$ is the $k$th branch of the inverse of the Lambert W function, then it is the same as $ue^u$, the inverse of the Lambert W function by definition.

Comment: I would start with $\mathcal{E}$ because it looks easier to manipulate into the other.